# Publish JavaScript Client over Apache cxf with Spring configuration

Tags: spring, apache, cxf, static-content

We are publishing a REST-API in our Server-Application. The Rest-API is configured with Spring and uses Apache cxf. The whole configuration is defined in xml and via Annotaions.

Now we have a JavaScript client that uses the rest-api and we want to publish the client (index.html,bundle.js,... ) with the webserver from apache cxf.
Example: `localhost:7564/api/v1/webapp`

We want to use the embedded web server from Apache cxf to publish the js client. No additinal Tomcat/Apache/... .

There are many exmaples with static-content but none of these are using Spring/ApacheCxf/embeddedWebserver and xml/Annotation-based configuration.

Any ideas?

xml configuration loaded in our Spring applicationcontext.xml:

```
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">
<!-- Apache CXF initiale Konfiguration -->
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />

<jaxrs:server
    id="jaxrsEmbeddedServer"
    address="http://0.0.0.0:7564/api/v1"  >

    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <bean class="com.isp.lea.service.web.api.v1.RootApi" /> 
        ...
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean
            id="cors-filter"
            class="org.apache.cxf.rs.security.cors.CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter" />
        ...
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:features>
        <ref bean="swagger2Feature" />
        ...
    </jaxrs:features>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Rest-api example:

```
@Path( "/" )
@SuppressWarnings( "javadoc" )
public class RootApi extends RestApi
{
  @GET
  @ApiOperation( value = "Hello World! ",
                 notes = "Notes...",
                 tags = { "apm" } )
  public String nichts()
  {
    return "Hello!";
  }
}
```

Comment: You can expose the static content by placing them in webapp folder right? Or do you want the static content to be served directly from cxf?

Comment: no, the embedded server do not expose any folder. When i call 'localhost:7564/api/v1/webapp' the webserver should return the js client(index.html).

Comment: The embedded server cannot run by itself. It has to be deployed on tomcat or a similar web server. That will expose the web-app folder. You can place you index.html and js file in webapp directory.